# my codeigniter captcha not generating image

Tags: php, codeigniter, captcha

My CodeIgniter captcha is not generating so I can't show it in my view

**Controller**

```
public function login() {
    $this->load->helper('captcha');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($this->login_rules);
    $userCaptcha = set_value('captcha');
    $word = $this->session->userdata('captchaWord');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE && strcmp(strtoupper($userCaptcha),strtoupper($word)) == 0) {
        $this->session->unset_userdata('captchaWord');
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');

        if(!$this->autentifikasi->login($username,$password)) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('pesan', '<div class="error">Login gagal</div>');
            redirect(site_url('user/login'));
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('pesan', '<div class="sukses">Anda telah berhasil login, selamat berbelanja.</div>');
            redirect(site_url('user/login'));
        }
    }

    $original_string = array_merge(range(0,9), range('a','z'), range('A', 'Z'));
    $original_string = implode("", $original_string);
    $captcha = substr(str_shuffle($original_string), 0, 6);

    $vals = array(
        'word' => $captcha,
        'img_path' => './captcha/',
        'img_url' => base_url().'user/login/',
        'font_path' => './fonts/texb.ttf',
        'img_width' => '150',
        'img_height' => 30,
        'expiration' => 3600
    );

    $cap = create_captcha($vals);

    $data['image']= $cap['image'];
    $this->session->set_userdata('captchaWord', $captcha);

    $this->template->set_judul('PT. Columbindo Perdana')
        ->set_css('style')
        ->set_parsial('sidebar','sidebar_view',$this->data)
        ->set_parsial('topmenu','top_view',$this->data)
        ->render('user_login',$this->data); 
}
```

**View**

```
    <?php if($this->session->flashdata('pesan')): ?>
    <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('pesan'); ?>
<?php else:?>
    <h2>Silakan Login</h2>
    <?php if(@$error){echo @$error;} ?>
    <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
    <br />
    <?php echo form_open(site_url(uri_string()),'class="order"'); ?>
    <?php echo form_label('Username'); ?>
    <?php echo form_input('username'); ?>
    <?php echo form_label('Password'); ?>
    <?php echo form_password('password'); ?>
    <?php echo form_label('Captcha'); ?>
    <?php echo $image; ?>
    <?php echo form_input('captcha'); ?>
    <?php echo form_submit('submit','Login'); ?>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
    <br />
    Anda belum memiliki akun? Silakan daftar <a href="<?php echo site_url('user/register') ;?>">disini</a>.
<?php endif ?>
```

As I know I didn't have captcha folder or font folder, is it still will be generate it self without those 2 folders? I already try what i can from some solved problem but it's still not working.  no error but the captcha image not show up.

please help me.

Comment: no, You need to create a captcha folder first in order to use captcha

Comment: oh, so i must create an empty folder 1st? not the folder which already have captcha image inside?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing `$this->data` to your view but you are assigning the image generated to `$data`.  So you need to change it from

```
$data['image']= $cap['image'];
```

to

```
$this->data['image']= $cap['image'];
```

If that doesn't work then make sure the captcha directory you are saving the image to (`'img_path' => './captcha/'`) is writable, either 666 or 777.  You can do this be doing `chmod 777 captcha/` on the command line.  Also make sure that the GD image library extension is enabled in your [php.ini](http://www.php.net/manual/en/image.installation.php)

Comment: how to make edit it to 666 or 777? and how to enable the GD image sir?

Comment: yes sir i already make it work with my own way i think.. when i generate it the i print_r($cap) and it's appear [word]=>asdasd [time]=> 1396421917.5709 [image] => ''

the image array is empty / null. but in captcha folder which i create there is appear an image with this name 1396421917.5709.jpg and i just alter the view for call it using <img src='/captcha/'$this->data->time'.jpg'>

hahaha.. i know it's wrong way but it's work so i think it's okey :)

thanks a lot sir. thank you for your time answering my question.

best regards