# Codeigniter captcha image cannot be written into captcha directory

Tags: php, codeigniter, captcha, chmod

I have created a login form with captcha image. It works well on my windows operating system. When I uploaded it to the server captcha image is not displayed. CI creates the image but cannot write it into captcha directory (CHMOD = 755) bacuse of permission settings. When I set CHMOD value of the directory to 777 (which I should not) it works well.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22589609/my-codeigniter-captcha-not-generating-image) there is a question similar to mine but proposed and accepted answer is not secure, I guess.

How can I say CI to write the file that it created into the directory using ftp credentials on the fly or is there another way?

I am afraid of encountering further problems like file upload operations (like profile picture change, attachments to the announcements) by the users.

Comment: Does it work also for `755` permissions? (It's more "secured" than 777)

Comment: @OfirBaruch no value is already 755

Comment: Can't you change the permissions to 777 before file write operation and change it to 755 after operation is complete ?

Comment: have you checked `group:owner` permission, folder `group:owner` should also have to `apache` or `nobody`

Comment: gorup and owner are 1073 (myid)

Answer (score 0):

I got around the permission problem by not writing a file at all.

I modified the library in system/plugins/captcha_pi.php to return the image data for inline inclusion.  The other return values are the same (timestamp and captcha phrase).

So instead of writing to a file, it returns the inline image content instead.